# Lemma 8.2.5 Analysis by Tao (set theory)

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $X$ be a set (which could be uncountable), and let $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that the series $\sum_{x \in X}f(x)$ is absolutely convergent. Then the set $\{x \in X : f(x) \not=0\}$ is at most countable. (Hint: first show if $M$ is the quantity 
>   $$M : = \sup \{\sum_{x\in A} |f(x)| : A \subset X , \text{$A$ finite}\}$$
>   then the sets $\{x \in X : |f(x)| > 1/n\}$ are finite with cardinality at most $Mn$ for every positive integer $n$. Then use Exercise 8.1.9 (which uses the axiom of choice).
>
> Exercise 8.1.9 shows that $\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} A_{\alpha}$ is at most countable if $I$ and $A_{\alpha}$ are at most countable.

Attept: We have that $\{x \in X: f(x) \not=0\} = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\{x \in X : |f(x)| > 1/n\}$. Then, the result follows from Exercise 8.1.9. But, I don't know how to prove the statement "$\{x \in X : |f(x)| > 1/n\}$ are finite with cardinality at most $Mn$ for every positive integer $n$". I appreciate if you give some help.

Comment: I suggest you evaluate the partial sum over this set, which must have finite value.

Comment: @Theleb If you don't mind, could you be more specific please?